# Moving point to center of polygon using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a polygon layer of watersheds and a point layer of tree planting locations. Because of privacy reasons, I can't display the exact location of tree plantings, so instead I'd like to display them in the center of whichever watershed they're in.

How do I go about this using ArcGIS Pro 2.7.

Comment: Do you want to change exact location of trees (in dataset) to center of the polygon or just visualize (without changing them in dataset)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use python and move the points to each watershed centroid. Start by intersecting your watersheds and plantings to transfer some watershed identifier to your point layer. Then:

```py
import arcpy

watershed = r'C:\folder\data.gdb\watersheds' #Change
planting = r'C:\folder\data.gdb\planting_intersected_with_watersheds' #Change
watershed_id_field = r'watershedid' #Change

watershed_centroids = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(watershed, [watershed_id_field, 'SHAPE@XY'])} #Dictionary of watershed id as key, and centroid xy as value
#Move each point
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(planting, [watershed_id_field, 'SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in watershed_centroids:
            row[1] = watershed_centroids[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that tree location layer (point) is not necessary when you have polygon feature of watershed. You can simply use polygon feature class of your watershed and use  ***Feature To Point*** from the **Data management toolbox**. Simply uncheck the  "**Inside**" option if it is checked, this way resultant point feature will be calculated at the center of gravity (**centroid**)  of watershed polygon feature. The resulting points equal number of polygons in your input feature layer.